# Is there a way to see my retweets within a date range?

Tags: twitter

I know that I can see my own tweets within a date range by doing something like this:

`from:@username until:2019-01-01 since:2018-01-01`

But is there a way I can see other peoples tweets that I have retweeted during a date range?
I'm happy to use a platform like TweetDeck if it's not possible in the native Twitter search interface.

Answer (score 2):

The correct filter is:

```
(from:username) since:2019-01-01 until:2020-01-01 -filter:replies +filter:nativeretweets
```

See this [Elon Musk](https://twitter.com/search?q=(from%3Aelonmusk)%20since%3A2019-01-01%20until%3A2020-01-01%20-filter%3Areplies%20%2Bfilter%3Anativeretweets&src=typed_query) example:

https://twitter.com/search?q=(from%3Aelonmusk)%20since%3A2018-01-01%20-filter%3Areplies%20%2Bfilter%3Anativeretweets&src=typed_query

Comment: thanks for this. Can you edit the answer to include "until" in the link? When I add in "until" it doesn't work for some reason. When I add it to the search query it doesn't work either

https://twitter.com/search?q=(from%3Aelonmusk)%20since%3A2018-01-01%20until%3A2019-01-01%20-filter%3Areplies%20%2Bfilter%3Anativeretweets&src=typed_query

Comment: I edited my answer. You are right, for some reason `until` does not work.

Comment: @JoshMcGee can you accept the answer as correct?

Comment: I don't think your answer provides a way for me to see my retweets of other people within a specified range of dates because your "until" suggestion doesn't work, which was my original query.